# Помогите получить значение переменной из другого класса

Tags: java, android

В `MainActivity` есть переменная `grad`. Ее значение нужно получать в `MyDraw`.
Ниже код. Что не так? Значение переменной в MyDraw всегда 0.0

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvListSen, tvTemp, tvHyd, tvOrient;
    Button btnListSen, btnTestSen;
    SensorManager sensorManager;
    List<Sensor> sensors;
    Sensor sensorLight, sensorTemp, sensorHyd, sensorAccel, sensorMagnet;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Timer timer;
    int rotation;


    SensorEventListener listenerLight = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            //tvListSen.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    };

    SensorEventListener listenerTemp = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            float fl = event.values[0];
            tvTemp.setText("Температура: "+ String.format("%.1f", fl)+"°C");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
    };

    SensorEventListener listenerHyd = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            float fl = event.values[0];
            tvHyd.setText("Влажность: "+String.format("%.1f", fl)+"%");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
    };

    float[] valaccel   = new float[3];
    float[] valmagnet  = new float[3];
    float[] valresult  = new float[3];
    float[] valresult2 = new float[3];
    private float grad;

    public float GetGrad(){
        return this.grad;
    }

    SensorEventListener listenerAccel = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
                valaccel[i]=event.values[i];
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
    };

    SensorEventListener listenerMagnet = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
                valmagnet[i]=event.values[i];
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
    };

    float[] r = new float[9];

    void GetDeviceOrientation (){
        sensorManager.getRotationMatrix(r,null, valaccel, valmagnet);
        sensorManager.getOrientation(r, valresult);
        valresult[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(valresult[0]);
        valresult[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(valresult[1]);
        valresult[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(valresult[2]);
        return;
    }

    float[] Rin =new float[9];
    float[] Rout=new float[9];

    void GetActDevOrientation(){
        sensorManager.getRotationMatrix(Rin, null, valaccel, valmagnet);
        int X_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_X;
        int Y_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_Y;
        switch (rotation){
            case (Surface.ROTATION_0):
                break;
            case (Surface.ROTATION_90):
                X_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_Y;
                Y_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X;
                break;
            case (Surface.ROTATION_180):
                Y_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y;
                break;
            case (Surface.ROTATION_270):
                X_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y;
                Y_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_X;
                break;
            default:break;
        }
        sensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(Rin, X_axis, Y_axis, Rout);
        sensorManager.getOrientation(Rout, valresult2);
        valresult2[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(valresult2[0]);
        valresult2[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(valresult2[1]);
        valresult2[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(valresult2[2]);
        return;
    }

    String format(float values[]){
        return String.format("%1$.1f\t\t%2$.1f\t\t%3$.1f", values[0], values[1], values[2]);
    }

    void ShowInfo(){
        sb.setLength(0);
        sb  .append("Orientation: "+ format(valresult))
            .append("\nOrientation2: "+ format(valresult2));
        tvOrient.setText(String.format("%.1f", valresult[0]));
        grad = valresult[0];
    }

    void GraphMod(){
    }

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //tvListSen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvListSen);
        tvTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTemp);
        tvHyd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHyd);
        tvOrient = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOrient);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
        sensorLight = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
        sensorTemp  = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
        sensorHyd   = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY);
        sensorAccel = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorMagnet= sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(listenerMagnet, sensorMagnet, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        sensorManager.registerListener(listenerAccel, sensorAccel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //сюда поместить действия__________
                        GetDeviceOrientation();
                        GetActDevOrientation();
                        ShowInfo();
                        GraphMod();

                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 400);
        WindowManager windowManager = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        rotation = display.getRotation();
        //tvHyd.setText(deg);
    }

    public void OnClickbtnListSens(View v) {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(listenerLight, sensorLight);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(listenerTemp, sensorTemp);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(listenerHyd, sensorHyd);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Sensor sensor: sensors){
            sb.append("Name: ").append(sensor.getName())
                    .append("\nType: ").append(sensor.getType())
                    .append("\nVendor: ").append(sensor.getVendor())
                    .append("\nResolution: ").append(sensor.getResolution())
                    .append("\nMaxRange: ").append(sensor.getMaximumRange())
                    .append("\n ======== \n");
        }
        //tvListSen.setText(sb);
    }

    public void OnClickbtnTestSen(View v){
        sensorManager.registerListener(listenerLight, sensorLight, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        sensorManager.registerListener(listenerTemp, sensorTemp, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        sensorManager.registerListener(listenerHyd, sensorHyd, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(listenerLight, sensorLight);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(listenerTemp, sensorTemp);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(listenerHyd, sensorHyd);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(listenerAccel, sensorAccel);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(listenerMagnet, sensorMagnet);
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

**Код MyDraw**:

```
public class MyDraw extends View {

    Paint p;
    //float deg;
    int Width, Heidht, x, y;
    //int[] x = new int[360];
    //int[] y = new int[360];
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Path path, path1;
    Matrix matrix;
    MainActivity mAct = new MainActivity();


    public MyDraw(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        p = new Paint();
        path  = new Path();
        matrix = new Matrix();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        float deg = mAct.GetGrad();

        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
        Width = canvas.getWidth();
        Heidht = canvas.getHeight();
        //синий конец стрелки
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo((Width/2-50), (Heidht/2));
        path.lineTo((Width/2), (Heidht/2-250));
        path.lineTo((Width/2+50), (Heidht/2));
        path.close();
        p.setStrokeWidth(2);
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.setRotate(deg, Width/2, Heidht/2);
        path.transform(matrix);
        canvas.drawPath(path, p);
        //красный конец стрелки
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(Width/2-50, Heidht/2);
        path.lineTo(Width/2, Heidht/2+250);
        path.lineTo(Width/2+50, Heidht/2);
        path.close();
        p.setStrokeWidth(2);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        path.transform(matrix);
        canvas.drawPath(path, p);

        p.setTextSize(70);
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        // рисуем текст в точке (150,500)
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(deg), 10, 70, p);

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Господа. Помогите советом и примером, если не сложно. Я еще новичек в этом деле.

Comment: Существуют общие соглашения, по которым имена методов следует начинать с маленькой буквы. С большой буквы принято называть имена классов.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том что вы в классе `MyDraw` создаете новый объект `MainActivity`, который не имеет ничего общего с активити, которая отображается на экране и значение который вы хотите получить, поэтому метод `GetGrad` возвращает значение переменной по умолчанию, которые было создано при создании объекта. Один из способо решить проблему это добавить метод `setGrad` в класс `MyDraw` и устанавливать значение из вне через него.

Comment: В MainActivity опрашиваются сенсоры и присваивается значение переменной grad. В MyDraw я даже не знаю значения с этих сенсоров. При этом оба класса это один экран(одна активити). Идея в том, чтобы в MainActivity получить и обработать показания с датчиков, а в MyDraw на основе обработанных показаний нарисовать что-то.

Comment: @Konstantin Вы в ```MyDrawe``` создали новый объект ```MainActivity```. Несмотря но то, что тип у них одинаковый, это 2 разных объекта, которые имеют собственные значения для переменной ```grad```. Т.к. в объекте ```MyDraw``` переменная не изменяется, соответственно и возвращается 0. Я вижу выход только в передаче значений из вне, либо использовать что-то типа EventBus, но мне кажется это не лучший вариант

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я догнал.

Answer (score 1):

Вы же заполняете переменную `grad` только в методе `ShowInfo`. Вот она у Вас и проинициализирована значением по умолчанию.

Вот Ваш код:

```
void ShowInfo(){
    sb.setLength(0);
    sb  .append("Orientation: "+ format(valresult))
        .append("\nOrientation2: "+ format(valresult2));
    tvOrient.setText(String.format("%.1f", valresult[0]));
    grad = valresult[0]; // Вы присваиваете новое значение переменной grad, но если valresult[0] == 0.0, то значение не изменится
}
```

То есть пока Вы не вызовите метод `ShowInfo` у Вас так и будет значение по умолчанию `0.0`. Ну либо меняйте значение в другом месте.

Comment: Привел полный код 'MainActivity'. 'ShowInfo' вызывается, 'valresult[0]' имеет конкретное значение. не равно 0

Comment: @Konstantin, то есть в строке `grad = valresult[0];` присваивается конкретное значение? И Вы отладились и уверены в этом?

Comment: в переменной valresult[0] число <>0. Это точно.  Это число выводится в tvOrient(текст на экране). следовательно переменная grad содержит это же число. Я так думаю.

Comment: @Konstantin а вы не гадайте, а запустите в режиме дебаггера и проверьте

Comment: @Konstantin, Поставьте точку останова и удостоверьтесь в том, что туда приходит не 0. Попробуйте вызвать сначала метод `ShowInfo`, а затем  `GetGrad` и поместите полученное значение во временную переменную и посмотрите, что вернул Вам второй метод, после того, как в первом присвоилось точно не нулевое значение. И тогда уже не будем гадать, а будем знать.

Comment: да я уверен, что переменная grad в mainActivity не нулевая. При этом в классе MyDraw вместо значения ноль.

Comment: @Konstantin, как-то странно у Вас получается. Вы внутри класса `MyDraw` создаете объект `MainActivity`, один раз вызываете метод `GetGrad` и говорите, что у Вас там есть значение, хотя на самом деле Вы его там нигде не меняете. А говорите, что уверены в том, что там не ноль. Ну как?

Comment: В `MainActivity` опрашиваются сенсоры и присваивается значение переменной `grad`. В `MyDraw` я даже не знаю значения с этих сенсоров. При этом оба класса это один экран(одна активити). Идея в том, чтобы в `MainActivity` получить и обработать показания с датчиков, а в `MyDraw` на основе обработанных показаний нарисовать что-то. Я только учусь и возможно что-то не правильно объясняю. Нет цели из `MyDraw` что-то поменять внутри `MainActivity`. Я хочу просто прочитать оттуда переменную. Пробовал делать ее public эффекта никакого.